# Dynamic custom RazorViewEngine?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

We have a custom `RazorViewEngine` based on a theme.

```
public CustomViewEngine(string theme)
{
  PartialViewLocationFormats = new[]
  {
    "~/Views/PartialViews/" + theme + "/{0}.cshtml",
    "~/Views/PartialViews/Base/{0}.cshtml"
  };  // This is simplified, we actually have some themes falling back to some other themes before falling back to Base
}

protected void Application_Start()
{
  string theme = GetTheme(); // read from config file
  ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
  ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new CustomViewEngine(theme));
}
```

When the theme is **static** (eg. from a config file and never changes) this is all **good**.

But now we need the theme to be **dynamic** (the user will be able to change it).
What is the best way of doing this?

Setting the `ViewEngine` on page load (in the `Controller`, instead of in `Application_Start`) works if requests come one at a time, but I am afraid it could load the wrong theme when people are hitting the page at the same time.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
    string selectedTheme = GetUserTheme(); // eg. HttpContext.Current.Request["theme"]

    // Reset ViewEngine every page load because selectedTheme may have changed
    ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
    ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new CustomViewEngine(selectedTheme));

    // Putting Thread.Sleep here (to simulate concurrent requests) and opening multiple
    // tabs with different theme selections will make some tabs load the wrong theme :(

    return View();
  }
}
```

How do you correctly get `CustomViewEngine` to select the right theme and be robust on **concurrent** requests?

Or is there a way to **override** the ViewEngine logic so that we can write our own function to locate the .cshtml file (instead of just passing an array of possible file locations)?

**EDIT:**

Apparently the solution is to override `FileExists`, although it makes page loads slower.

```
protected override bool FileExists(ControllerContext controllerContext, string virtualPath)
{
    // Do your own logic here, look up Request and return true or false
    return base.FileExists(controllerContext, virtualPath);
}
```

http://robhead89.blogspot.com/2014/01/aspnet-viewengine-caching-and-how-to.html

Comment: By safe, do you mean thread safe?  I would be inclined to store the user's preference in a database and fetch/store it in the session.  Last question is confusing because it looks like you're doing exactly that in the code?

Comment: I am not sure if I am doing it right. So are you saying the ViewEngine is session-specific? So when many people are hitting the page at the exact same time it will still render the correct theme based on their preference?

Comment: I've been caught out by unexpected threading so I understand your concern there.  Session data is thread safe.  I can't see anything in your code that would cause threading issues, but I would look closely at what's happening in `GetUserTheme()` for potential issues.

Comment: Ah yes for example if it instead used `HttpContext.Current.Session["theme"]`.

Comment: Note that the session is between the web server and the client's browser.  If your web server hosts multiple applications, they will share session space for that one client (until the browser is closed or the session expires).  I write a lot of Intranet web apps so I usually compartmentalise session data by prefixing an application name to the variable name, eg: `Session["applicationA_colour"]`, `Session["applicationB_colour"]`.  On the other hand, this can be handy if there are shared variables such as a staffId

Comment: Thank you Khyron for your help, but I just tried putting Thread.Sleep and it broke it :(  See my edited post.

Comment: I think I found a solution. Thanks again Khyron